# Как запустить powershell команду из python, без появления окна PS?

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

Подскажите, как отключить появление powershell окна при запуске скрипта внутри Python.
В программе есть строка такого вида:

```
subprocess.check_output(['powershell.exe', 'start-process explorer'], universal_newlines=True)
```

Вроде нашел параметры на тихий запуск:

```
-nologo -noninteractive -windowstyle hidden
```

Но не могу понять, куда его вставить в коде...
Также, с подобной командой на мгновенье тоже появляется окно PowerShell'a:

```
subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe -nologo -noninteractive -windowstyle hidden start-process explorer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать так, возможно решит твой вопрос :)

```
import subprocess

# Задаем команду PowerShell
command = 'powershell.exe Get-ChildItem C:\\'

# Запуск команды PowerShell в скрытом режиме
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, creationflags=0x08000000)
```

Опция `creationflags=0x08000000` используется для запуска PowerShell в скрытом режиме без появления окна.